# How can I add an animated gif in a :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I want to append an animated gif, using an `:after` pseudo element:

```
#shipment-history tbody .history-row .enroute:after {
    content:url(https://susscargologistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/green.gif);
    clear:both;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
```

I tried the above code. It does show the image, but it is not animated. The height and width also do not work.

Comment: I tested your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/09eqm7cv/ and the gif animates just fine. Can you share your actual HTML for the table?

Comment: <tr class="history-row">
       <td class="history-data date "></td>
       <td class="history-data time "></td>
       <td class="history-data location "></td>
       <td class="history-data status "></td>
       <td class="history-data updated-name "></td>
       <td class="history-data remarks "></td>
   </tr>

Comment: Please edit your question to add the HTML. Also, there is not element with the class `.enroute` in your HTML you did provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gif as a `background-image` into pseudo element instead of using it in the `content`.

```css
#shipment-history tbody .history-row .enroute:after {
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    display:block;
    background-image: url(https://susscargologistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/green.gif);
    background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="shipment-history">
<tbody>
  <tr class="history-row">
    <td class="enroute"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```